# Absolute value of difference of squares contradiction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Consider this formula:

$$\sqrt[4]{(z^2-1)^4}$$

If we expand it, we get $|z^2-1|$. Now, if $z=-1$, $|(-1)^2-1| = |1-1| = |0|$, so $|z^2-1| = z^2-1$.

On the other hand, $|z^2-1| = |z-1|*|z+1| = |-1-1|*|-1+1| = |-2|*|0|$, so $-(z-1)*(z+1) = -(z^2-1)$.

How's this possible?

Comment: note that $$2\cdot 0=0$$

Comment: How is *what* possible?  You have$ |z^2 - 1|= |-(z^2 - 1)|$.  What's the issue?  Nothing wrong with that at all.  And for 0 you have 0 = |0| = -|0| = -0. Nothing wrong with that.  And for z = 1 you have $z^2 - 1 = -(z^2 - 1) = 0$.  Nothing wrong with that.  Indeed if you are ever given a problem $-f(x) = f(x)$ you may conclude $f(x) = 0$.  (So if $z^2 - 1 = -1(z^2 -1)$ then $z^2 - 1 = 0$ so $z^2 = 1$ so $z =\pm 1$.) Nothing wrong with that.  Nothing wrong with anything I can see.

Comment: I thank everybody who answered for their time and patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a contradiction. It just so happens that
$$0=-0$$